# Aggregation/groupby using pymongo versus using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb

I have an API that loads data from MongoDB (with pymongo) and applies relatively "complex" data transformations with pandas afterwards, such as groupby on datetime columns, parametrizing the frequency and other stuff. Since I'm more expert in pandas than mongo, I do prefer doing it as it is, but I have no idea if writing these transformations as mongo aggregate queries would be significantly faster.

To simplify the question, not considering the difficulty on writing the queries on both sides: it's faster doing a [simple groupby on mongo and select * results] or [select * and doing it in pandas/dask(in a distributed scenario)]? Is the former faster/slower than the second in large datasets or smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general aggregation will be much faster than Pandas because the aggregation pipeline is:

- Uploaded to the server and processed there eliminating network latency associated with round trips
- Optimised internally to achieve the fastest execution
- Executed in C on the server will all the available threading as opposed to running
  on a single thread in Pandas
- Working on the same dataset within the same process which means your working set
  will be in memory eliminating disk accesses

As a stop gap I recommend pre-processing your data into a new collection using [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) and then using Panda to process that.